# Using Objects as Keys in Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

Is it a good practice to use your domain objects as keys in a Dictionary ?

I have a scenario where I populate my domain object using `NHibernate`.

For performing business logic I need to look-up Dictionary. I can make use of 
Either

```
IDictionary<int, ValueFortheObject>
```

or

```
Dictionary<DomainObject, ValueFortheObject>
```

The second options seems better to me as

1. I can write easier test cases and can use real domain objects in test cases as well rather than using `Mock<DomainObject>` (if I go with the first option) since setter on the `Id` is `private` on ALL domain objects.
2. The code is more readable as `Dictionary<Hobbit,List<Adventures>>` is more readable to me than `Dictionary<int,List<Adventures>>`  with comments suggesting int is the `hobbitId` especially when passing as parameters

<strike>My questions are :</strike>

1. What are advantages of using the first option over the second (which I might be blindly missing) ?
2. Will be any performance issues using the second approach?

Update 01:

My domain models  implement those and they DO NOT get mutated while performing the operations.

Will there be issues with performance using them as keys ? or am I completely missing the point here and performance / memory are not related to what keys are being used?

Update 02:

My question is

1. Will there be any issues with performance or memory if I use Objects as keys instead of primitive types and **WHY / HOW** ?

Comment: Are you familiar with Dictionary..? it utilizes Key/Value pair.. aslo it should not allow duplicate keys.. have you thought about Hashtable for example.. your Dictionary<int, List<Adventures>> looks more readable but without seeing any real code it's hard to determine what it is you are trying to do exactly in my opinion

Comment: Can you provide an Example, how you want to use the Dictionary specificly?

Comment: I used the technique of a quick and dirty way of counting occurrences in an array using it's index from another method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ScottChamberlain gives you the overall issue, but your use cases could argue either way.  Some questions you should ask yourself are: what does it mean for two business objects to be equal? Is this the same or different if they are being used as a key in a dictionary or if I'm comparing them elsewhere? If I change an object, should it's value as a key change or remain the same? If you use overrides for `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()`, what is the cost of computing those functions?

Generally I am in favor of using simple types for keys as there is a lot of room for misunderstanding with respect to object equality.  You could always create a custom dictionary (wrapper around `Dictionary<Key,Value>`) with appropriate method if readability is your highest concern.  You could then write the methods in terms of the objects, then use whatever (appropriate) property you want as the key internally.

Comment: My other concern is testing out the business logic. Using domain objects gives me freedom of writing simpler test cases. +1 for suggesting using a wrapper around the dictonary which solves my problem :)

Answer (score 4):

The biggest issue you will run in to is you must not mutate your key object while it is performing it's roll as a key.

When i say "mutate" I mean your key object must implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to be used as a key for a dictionary. Anything you do to the object while it is being used as a key must not change the value of `GetHashCode` nor cause `Equals` to evaluate to true with any other key in the collection.

Comment: Yes, my domain models do implement those and they DO NOT get mutated while performing the operations. will there be issues with performance using them as keys ? or am I completely missing the point here and performance / memory doesnt make much of a difference with respect to what keys are being used?